# Specific Theorem For Uniqueness of Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I'm currently studying Differential Equations for independent study. I've across the claim that given some ordinary differential equation (initial value problem) $f(t,y)$, if $f$ is continuous in some domain $D$ of the $yt$ plane, and the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is also continuous on that same domain, then we know that there exists some unique solution to the differential equation. Is this claim actually true? If so, is there a name or theorem associated with this result?

Answer (score 1):

The theorem states that:

> Let the functions $f$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ be continuous in some rectangle $\alpha<t<\beta$, $\gamma<y<\delta$ containing the point $(t_{0},y_{0})$. Then, in some interval $t_{0}-h<t<t_{0}+h$ contained in $\alpha<t<\beta$, there's aunique solution $y=\phi(t)$ of the initial value problem $$y'=f(t,y), \quad y(y_{0})=y_{0}$$

Note that is important the *initial condition* for the problem.
Here we note that the conditions stated in theorem are sufficients to guarentee the existence of a unique solution of the initial value problem in some interval $t_{0}-h<t<t_{0}+h$, but they're not necessary. That's the conclusion remains true under slightly weaker hypotheses about the function $f$. In fact, the existence of a solution but not its uniqueness can be established on the basis of the continuity of $f$ alone.

An important *geometrical consequence* of the uniqueness part of theorem is that the graph of *two solutions* can't intersect each other. Otherwise, there would be two solutions that satisfy the initial condition corresponding to the point of intersection, in contradiction to theorem.

Finally, you can read [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) for more information.

For your self-education I suggest you also read this [text online](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Supplemental_Modules_(Analysis)/Ordinary_Differential_Equations/2%3A_First_Order_Differential_Equations/2.8%3A_Theory_of_Existence_and_Uniqueness) which contains theorems and practical examples. Good luck!